# SQL Server 2012 Query Returning Duplicate Rows When Using Cross APPLY or CROSS-JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cross-join

Updating this post for better clarity.

The following issue is due to the CROSS-APPLY (I also hard a CROSS-JOIN), but I cannot find an easy way using an inner join or partition by to

1. make each record unique - no duplicates and also

2) make sure that each unique record is in order...174..175, 176, 177 etc. I expect about 3200 records here, not 174000 ish which I am getting.

Can someone provide their take as to what I can do to ensure I get the records in order? Thanks community! See code and data.

After executing the below query - I get the following results. As you see in the below data, if I order by Contract I get duplicates - which I am not supposed to do with Id's generated for each cross apply. The cross apply is causing these duplicates of the same record with different ids generated - the way it should work is once the record is created with the id - that should be the only instance of that record.

I have also highlighted in bold the parts of my code that get me the row id's following the latest max instance of the id from the previous selected row - but causes me duplication.

So for setting the expectation - the image below of a sub-select tells me what already exists in the table that I am referencing logic against - tells me what DOES NOT exist

[173 records - see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Qiw.png)

The next image tells me that my entire query is selecting what DOES NOT EXIST and generating the records starting at line 174 - that is very good but, I was alarmed at how many records I was getting - there are only 3875 distinct contracts so I should only be getting 3875 records - not 174ish as you see.

[Way too many records - see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjB4m.png)

So I re-ordered the query by Contract_TaskOrder - and I am seeing a ton of duplicates and re-assingnment of the duplicates a new id. See image below. The cross-apply is causing records for each unique instance of a contract in the [Stage].[BUD_PLN_Spendpln_Dataload_Staging_E_Grouped] table and creating how many times it is defined via a cartesian product - this is very very bad. I am trying to find a way with an inner join to do this - but to no avail.

[As you see - duplicates names of contracts - crap...see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MchpS.png)

Here is my full query - the bold parts need to be improved to allow for not only the duplicates to be removed but also the id to start from 174 and go in order for each unique NAME - tied to Contract-TaskOrder. If I just did a partition by to include the top 1 or max record of each combo I would have records with very widely sparsed ACLORDER ids based off the sequence.

```
    SELECT * FROM
                 (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                       'READWRITE' AS [ACCESSMODE],
                        3 AS [ACCESSMODEORDER],
                        **coalesce(const.maxs, 0) + row_number() over (
                        order by (select NULL)) AS [ACLORDER]**,
                        0 AS [ACLSFK],
                        'MEMBER' AS [FLAG],
                        4 AS [FLAGORDER],
                       'N' AS [ISUSER],
                        5 AS [ISUSERORDER],
                       ('SPS-Contract-' + Contract_TaskOrder) AS [NAME],
                       0 AS [NAMEORDER],
                       Contract_TaskOrder AS [OBJECTNAME],
                       1 AS [OBJECTNAMEORDER],
                      'SL_DIMENSION' AS [OBJECTTYPE],
                       2 AS [OBJECTTYPEORDER],
                      NULL AS [PARENT],
                      NULL AS [PARENTORDER] 
              FROM
       **[Stage].[BUD_PLN_Spendpln_Dataload_Staging_E_Grouped] cross apply (
            select max(ACLORDER) as maxs 
            from [BFS_ODI_WORK].[Stage].[BUD_PLN_SECURITY_MEMBERS] ) const 
   )**
   M 
WHERE
   1 = 1 
   AND NOT EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT
         1 
      FROM
         [BFS_ODI_WORK].[Stage].[BUD_PLN_SECURITY_MEMBERS] k 
      WHERE
         M.[NAME] = k.[NAME] 
         AND M.[FLAG] = k.[FLAG] 
         AND M.[OBJECTNAME] = k.[OBJECTNAME] 
         AND M.[OBJECTTYPE] = k.[OBJECTTYPE]
   )
order by
   NAME
```

Comment: I really can't figure out what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results really help.  Absent that, you should simplify the query to remove all the extraneous columns and tables to get to the issue you really need to solve.

Comment: Hi Gordon - my apologies - updating post to demonstrate where my issue lies.